# How do I center a div in the viewport within an overflowed parent div via mouseclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, center, viewport

UPDATE:  I have given this a couple shots to no avail!  Right now in my jsfiddle I have my work so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/virtuapete/x2pnC/2/

Below is the code used to "center" the "home" div.  Looking at it I realized its not aware of where the "home" div is currently located, therefore it blindly applies movement based on the array positioned with its origin in view in the upper left.

```
    container.overscroll({
    showThumbs:  false,
    scrollLeft:  1125,
    scrollTop:   1125
});

// Center "home" div in viewport
var gear = $('#gear');
gear.click(function() {
    var $foo = $('.id0'),
        elWidth = $foo.width(),
        elHeight = $foo.height(),
        elOffset = $foo.offset();
    container
        .scrollTop(elOffset.top + elHeight/2 - viewportHeight/2)
        .scrollLeft(elOffset.left + elWidth/2 - viewportWidth/2);
});
```

In it you can see the colored div array does not start out centered (the center div is outlined with a red border, follow the arrow on the edge of the viewport to find it if you like), I wish it was.  I found the options for Overscroll and there is a top & left offset for the starting position of the overscrolled object. Unfortunately it is asking for an integer for both in what looks like its use of JQuery scrollTop & scrollLeft. Maybe I can insert a pre-calculated variable in there instead of a straight integer?  I currently have it set to 1125px for each to get it in the view port for now atleast.

Theoretically I think its finding out the coordinate of the center of the "home" div on overscrolled object and aligning that on top of the calculated coordinate for the center of the viewport.  what does that look like programatically and is that the most efficient way of approaching the problem?

Comment: place the update in the question instead

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I took your advice and rewrote the body

Comment: so all you want to do is center the one bordered with red?

Comment: Yes, every time with a mouseclick the div bordered in red is scrolled to the center of the viewport, regardless of its current scrolled position... kind of like a 'go home' function

Comment: please validate your JS. jsfiddle reports an error. try clicking JSLint in jsfiddle to see what i mean.

Comment: that is an issue with JSfiddle (or JSLint), it is afterall an ALPHA project.  Lines 2 & 3 showing undefined on $ & window are part of JQuery variable definitions, which are fine.  If they weren't, the example wouldn't even work as much as it does.  JQuery is loading and those variables are being set, so its down to JSFiddle & JSLint on the site.  There are others that see this exact issue already and it is a known bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `elOffset = $foo.offset();` to  `elOffset = $foo.position()`

[.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns the position of an element relative to the visible area (viewport). [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) returns the position relative to the containing element (parent). that's why you can't calculate how much to scroll off to the left and top coz you got the wrong values.

i cannot center it well though, must be the margins between boxes throwing me off target but here's another part i changed:

```
container.scrollTop(elOffset.top - ((viewportHeight - elHeight) / 2)).scrollLeft(elOffset.left);
```

i [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2pnC/5/) here.